# Insert query gives "Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt" warning but sends still data to database

Tags: php, mysqli, insert, prepared-statement, fetch

I have a form with 2 drop down lists. Both with values from database tables.
When a visitor submits then the next things will occure:

1. A `select` query will compare the choices (id's)/POST values with the values (id's) in the database tables. The query will be fetched in the while loop. In the while loop is a if-else which controls if the values are equal to each other. When they are then run else.
2. In `else` there is the `insert` query which saves the values (id's) in a new database table.

I use prepared statements for both the `select` and the `insert` queries.
After fetching the select query I close it in else (`$selControl->close();`) and start the 2nd query (insert).

- When I run the website with a submit then I get the error "Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt" for the select query. But still it works and inserts into the DB table.
- When I write `$selControl->close();` (inclusive/exclusive `$insKeuze->close();` from insert) after `}` of the 3rd `else` or after `}` after `while` then I get the error that the 1st query must be closed before a new prepare statement (that's logic).
- Without a close statement gives also a "close-before-prepare" error.

I updated my code.
I added bind_param. It sends the data to the database, but gives the error.

What do I need to do to stop the error?

**If someone can help me, thanks in advance!**

#### The code: insert.php

```
<?php 
// Include database configuration file
include ("dbConfig.php");  

$kLand = $_POST["landen"];
$kGerecht = $_POST["gerechten"];

// If submit and landKeuze is not empty and gerechtKeuze is not empty
// --> control and validate the values and send to database.
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($kLand) && !empty($kGerecht)) 
{

   // If query is prepared then execute the query.
   // Query to select data from table landen with inner join table gerechten.
   if ($selControl = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT landen.land_id, gerechten.gerecht_id FROM landen INNER JOIN gerechten ON landen.land_id = gerechten.land_id WHERE landen.land_id = ? AND gerechten.gerecht_id = ?")) 
   {
      $selControl->bind_param("ii", $kLand, $kGerecht);
      if (!$selControl->execute()) 
      {
         echo "Failed to execute the query controle: " . $mysqli->error;
      }
      else 
      {
         $selControl->bind_result($lLand_id, $gGerecht_id);
         while ($selControl->fetch()) // <-- Coudn't fetch
         {
            // If selected land (land_id) is not the same as land_id in table landen
            // or selected gerecht (gerecht_id) is not the same as gerecht_id in table gerechten --> send echo.
            if ($kLand != $lLand_id || $kGerecht != $gGerecht_id) 
            {
               // Message when the combination is not correct
               echo "<script>alert('Deze combinatie bestaat niet. Doe een nieuwe poging!');</script>";
            }
            // Else insert the selected values in table landGerecht.
            else 
            {
               $selControl->close();

               // If query is prepared --> bind the columns and execute the query.
               // Insert statement with placeholders for the values to database table landGerecht
               if ($insKeuze = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO lab_stage_danush . landGerecht (land_id, gerecht_id) VALUES ( ?, ?)")) 
               {
                  // Bind land_id and gerecht_id as integers with $landKeuze and $gerechtKeuze.
                  $insKeuze->bind_param('ii', $kLand, $kGerecht);
                  // If statement is not executed then give an error message.
                  if (!$insKeuze->execute()) 
                  {
                     echo "Failed to execute the query keuze: " . $mysqli->error;
                  }
                   $insKeuze->close();
                }
                // Else give an error message.
                else 
                {
                    echo "Something went wrong in the query keuze: " . $mysqli->error;
                } 
             }
          } 
       }
    }
    else 
    {
    print_r($mysqli->error);
    }
    // After sent to database go back to keuze.php.
    echo "<script>location.replace('keuze.php');</script>";
}
?>
```

This structure gives the same error:

```
<?php
while ($selControl->fetch())
{
    echo "<script>alert('". $kLand . $kGerecht . $lLand_id . $gGerecht_id . "')</script>";
    // If selected land (land_id) is not the same as land_id in table landen
    // or selected gerecht (gerecht_id) is not the same as gerecht_id in table gerechten --> send echo.
    if ($kLand == $lLand_id && $kGerecht == $gGerecht_id)
    {
        $selControl->close();

        // If query is prepared --> bind the columns and execute the query.
        // Insert statement with placeholders for the values to database table landGerecht
        if ($insKeuze = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO lab_stage_danush . landGerecht (land_id, gerecht_id) VALUES ( ?, ?)"))
        {
            // Bind land_id and gerecht_id as integers with $landKeuze and $gerechtKeuze.
            $insKeuze->bind_param('ii', $kLand, $kGerecht);

            // If statement is not executed then give an error message.
            if (!$insKeuze->execute())
            {
                echo "Failed to execute the query keuze: " . $mysqli->error;
            }
            $insKeuze->close();
        } else // Else give an error message.
            {
                echo "Something went wrong in the insert query connection: " . $mysqli->error;
            }

    } else // Else insert the selected values in table landGerecht.
        {
            // Message when the combination is not correct
            echo "<script>alert('Deze combinatie bestaat niet. Doe een nieuwe poging!');</script>";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just something I see off the bat.. `hack_filter` but the real hack filter is `bind_param` which you didn't use after using prepare in your `select` Remove that filter and instead opt for finishing off your prepared statement.

Comment: To answer your mini question; `Do I have to add bind_param() before execute() to bind landen.land_id and gerechten.gerecht_id with variables?` You use `bind_param()` to put variables in your query, this MUST be done before you `->execute`. You use `bind_result()` to get the results AFTER you run `->execute`

Comment: You're getting that error likely because the `->prepare` failed on your `select`. Please locate the closing `if statment` bracket for `$selControl = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT...` and throw an `}else{ print_r($mysqli->error); }` to locate the actual issue.

Comment: Finaly, I see some calls to `error` like: `$insKeuze->error;` and `$selControl->error`. This is wrong. The statement/query doesn't return the error, it's actually mysqli that does. the correct statement here would be `$mysqli->error`

Comment: @WillParky93 So if I understand you right, trim, stripslashes and htmlspecialchars are not necessary to get safe post values? I use them to filter the values when someone change the values in the source code (F12)

Comment: Correct. Maybe with the old `mysql` function this may have been required. Throwing `$_POST` and `$_GET` directly into `bind_param` is safe as long as the server is set up correctly.

Comment: @WillParky93 I added bind_param() in my code now (`$selControl->bind_param("ii", $lLand, $gGerecht);`) but then I get the error: _Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement_. I select 2 columns, so I bind also 2 parameters? Why do I get this error?

Comment: May you please update your code on SO to reflect the changes you have made?

Comment: @WillParky93 I updated my code. Could you look at it, please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure why you are getting that error, looks like you are binding correctly. Try outputting the variables you are inputting and ensuring they are not null

Comment: @WillParky93 I tested it with `echo "<script>alert('". $kLand . $kGerecht . $lLand_id . $gGerecht_id . "')</script>";` in `while ($selControl->fetch()){ }`. When I select on the webpage for example land 2 and dish 4 then I get the alert with 2424. So I can conclude that both the POST values as the values directly from the tables are not null.

Comment: Without `$selControle->close();` and without the next (insert) query then there is no fetch error.. I commented all code and deleted the // line after line to check what happens every step.

Comment: So `$lLand_id` and `$gGerecht_id` are getting set, is this error you are getting on the `insert` ? I have trouble tagging your name so I apologize.

Comment: @WillParky93 No problem :) I get notifications when someone answers, so is okay. I think the problem is that I use 2 queries after each other in combination with the if-else if-else construction. I tried to flip the if-else to `if ($kLand == $lLand_id && $kGerecht == $gGerecht_id)` and placed `$selControl->close();` and the if-else insert (`$insKeuze`) prepared statement in this if and in the else 'The combination is not correct'. But then I get also the couldn't fetch error. So maybe I have to work with a complete different construction, but I don't know how.

Comment: Have you considered making a [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for this? When I get a spare 30 minutes I'll write a class up that you can use that *should* work

Comment: @WillParky93 Wow! That's very nice from you! I never worked with php classes. My school didn't teach us that.

Comment: Did you have any issues using it or understanding it?

Comment: @WillParky93 I works great! Thanks a lot! I get the values in my database. 
There are only a few things in PhpStorm, but maybe it is only a PhpStorm issue, but not for the webpage. The line `$stmt->bind_result($lLand_id, $gGerecht_id);` gives a red warning because of `$lLand_id` and `$gGerecht_id`. And PhpStorm gives yellow warnings for `prepare`, `bind_param`, `execute`, `bind_result` and `fetch`.  
And the echo "Post variables are not set!" is that temporarily? Because it's already visible before making a selection and after submit.

Comment: The red error stands for 'Undefined variable' and the yellow errors stand for 'Method prepare not found', 'Method fetch not found', etc. Not big problems, because it works well.

Comment: I've adjusted the code to reflect the changes. I'm pretty sure we don't need to `bind_result` so I've removed the call alltogether. I've removed the `echo "Post variables are not set!" ` as i didn't realize this was on the same page of your form. I'm not sure why PHPStorm is acting like that, but that's just an IDE error. Happy to hear it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as you said in the comments, you believe you're getting a conflict between your mysql connections. I've gone ahead and created a class that should resolve this.

landen.php

```
 class landen{

    //define our connection variable, this is set in __construct
    private $mysqli;
    //this function is called when you create the class. $l = new landen($mysqlconn)
    public function __construct($mysqli){
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    //setter for kLand
    private $kLand = 0;
    public function setKland($k){
        $this->kLand = $k;
    }

    //setter for kGerecht
    private $kGerecht = 0;
    public function setKGerecht($k){
        $this->kGerecht = $k;
    }

    //run is our main function here.
    //if there was a return from select, it runs the insert.
    //will return true if select + insert BOTH pass.
    public function run(){
        if($this->select()){
            return $this->insert();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private function select(){
        $q = "SELECT landen.land_id, gerechten.gerecht_id FROM landen INNER JOIN gerechten ON landen.land_id = gerechten.land_id WHERE landen.land_id = ? AND gerechten.gerecht_id = ?";
        if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($q)){
            $stmt->bind_param("ii",$this->kLand,$this->kGerecht);
            if($stmt->execute()){

                while ($stmt->fetch()){
                    /*
                    In your original code, you had a check to see if 
                    your post variable was the same as your returned query variables. 
                    This was not required as you are selecting from your database with those. 
                    They will **always** equal the post variables.

                    Line I'm disputing:  if ($kLand != $lLand_id || $kGerecht != $gGerecht_id) 
                    */  

                    return true;

                }
            }else{
                print_r("Error in select execute: {$this->mysqli->error}");
            }
        }else{
            print_r("Error in select prepare: {$this->mysqli->error}");
        }
        return false;
    }

    private function insert(){
        $q = "INSERT INTO lab_stage_danush . landGerecht (land_id, gerecht_id) VALUES ( ?, ?)";
        if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($q)){
            $stmt->bind_param("ii",$this->kLand,$this->kGerecht);
            if($stmt->execute){
                return true;
            }else{
                print_r("Error in insert execute {$this->myqsli->error}");
            }
        }else{
            print_r("Error in insert prepare {$this->mysqli->error}");
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

And here's an example on how you run this;
insert.php

```
<?php
require_once("dbConfig.php");  

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST['landen']) && !empty($_POST['gerechten'])){
    //Call the class code when we need it
    require_once("landen.php");
    //create the class when we need it.
    $landen = new landen($mysqli);

    //set our variables
    $landen->setKland($_POST['landen']);
    $landen->setKGerecht($_POST['gerechten']);

    //landen run returns True if the select + insert statment passed.
    //It will return false if they fail.
    //if they fail, the page will not change and the errors will be outputted.
    //Or it's failing because nothing has been returned by the select function.

    if($landen->run()){
        //send out header to go to Keuze page,
        //you had a javascript location function here.
        header("Location: keuze.php");
        die();
    }else{
        //by default, let's say our queries are running fine and the only reason the select failed is because
        //the database couldn't find anything.
        echo "Nothing found with {$_POST['landen']} and {$_POST['gerechten']}. Please try again!";
    }

}
```